# SwiftMailer corrupt attachment with dynamic content(using mandrill)

Tags: php, email-attachments, swiftmailer, mandrill

How can I attach dynamic content from mandrill webhook, and send it by using Swiftmailer and SMTP(Mandrill).

here is my code:

```
<?php   

if(!isset($_POST['mandrill_events'])) {
echo 'A mandrill error occurred: Invalid mandrill_events';
exit;
}

// -------------- Receive --------------------------
$mail = array_pop(json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events']));


// ----------------- Send ----------------------------------------
include_once "swiftmailer-master/lib/swift_required.php";

$subject = $mail->msg->subject . " From " . $mail->msg->from_email;
$from = array('info@myDomain.ir' =>'myDomain');
$to = array(
  'myEmail@yahoo.com' => 'Hamed Gh'
);

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 25,tls);
$transport->setUsername('username');
$transport->setPassword('***********');

$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);

//I think there is a problem here!!
foreach ($mail->msg->attachments as $attachment) {
$myType = $attachment->type;
$myName = $attachment->name;
$myContent = $attachment->content;

$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance()
      ->setFilename($myName)
      ->setContentType($myType)
      ->setBody($myContent)
      ;
$message->attach($attachment);
}

$body = $mail->msg->html;
$message->setBody($body, 'text/html');

$message->setTo($to);

$text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

if($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures) )
{
 echo 'Message successfully sent!';
} else {
 echo "There was an error:\n";
 print_r($failures);
}
?>
```

I search throughly and read SwiftMailer docs but I couldn't find a way that solve my problem.all attachment will be corrupt at destination!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content of attached files in Mandrill are Base64 encoded by default  (see. base64 field in the Json).

So before set attached content in SwiftMailer, you need to decode the content.

```
$myContent = base64_decode($attachment->content);
```